# База данных сайта велика

Tags: wordpress, сервер, хостинг, хранилище

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь и совет! Возникла такая ситуация: база товаров сайта слишком велика (весит около 100гб+). Сайт на Вордпрессе. Обычный хостинг или сервер будет очень слаб для того объемного сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-либо сервер или инструменты для того, чтоб сайт быстро работал. Возможно, поможет перенос сайта на Shopify?

P.S. я не разработчик)

Спасибо!

Comment: 100Гб для нормального сервера это очень мало и ни о чём.

Comment: Если нормально всё написано то среднестатистический сервер это потянет иначе никакой дата центр вам не поможет

Comment: Точно база 100гб или же вместе с файлами? Кол-во товаров/вариаций, клиентов, заказов исчисляется миллионами? Если нет, то база очень большая и нужно провести её оптимизацию Но не через PMA!!!. Так можно убить сайт. В общем нужен специалист по ВП.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно оптимизировать базу данных. Вы используете wordpress и Wocoomerce (скорее всего этот плагин). Проблема заключается в том, что все товары, страницы, посты, ссылки на галерею хранятся в одной таблице ( wp_posts) базы данных. Поэтому чем больше записей, тем медленнее будет работать сайт. Эту таблицу необходимо оптимизировать. Варианты могут быть разные. Например: в одной таблице будут ссылки на изображения, во второй ссылки на товары, которые начинаются на определенную букву и т.д. Но чтобы все это работало, также нужно переписать некоторые части сайта.